# Spring REST security: how to implement “two step” authentication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

We are building a management console application (REST API services) for managing databases and servers (VMs and containers). The API services may be called by web-based frontend (like ReactJS) and by remote http clients (like SDKs).

Due to various reasons, we’ll need to implement a “two step” authentication using Spring boot MVC and spring security. The steps are like this: 1) application level authentication, 2) and then DB/OS  level authentication.

Let me describe the two steps briefly:

1. application user or http clients may login using username/password that are stored in the central management repository. Once logged in, users/clients are permitted to view information about managed targets (DBs, and Servers). The information may be collected by certain tools and is stored in the management repository.
2. When the application user/client wants to connect to the managed targets, a remote connection  needs to be established and cached - therefore, DB/OS authentication is required.

My questions are:

a. In general, what solution/best practice do you recommend to meet the requirements?

b. For the app-level authentication, what authentication methods could be used - Basic Auth, Form Login, or a combination of them? and how to implement?

c. For the second step (DB/OS level authentication), I have no idea about how to implement it. Please comment or point me to some docs/code snippets.

d. When there are multiple targets, we’ll need to check if an existing connection can be obtained from the “cache”, before asking for credentials to create a new connection. How can we check and decide if authentication is required, on a per-target basis? What’s the best way to cache the connection - http session, SecurityContex, or else?

Please help. Any ideas, comments, directions are much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can only give you an advice regarding b). Question a) is way too broad for me to give  you an useful advice. Without knowing more about involved technologies I can not give you any advice on c) or d) either.

If you plan on building a a REST-API for a SPA, I would recommend using a JWT Token for Authentication. There are lots of tutorials on the internet available on how to implement JWT tokens. You can configure a JwtTokenFilter that processes incoming requests and - if a JWT token is contained in the request - loads the Principal in the SecurityContextHolder.

As pointed out [in this article](http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/), storing session data in the JWT token might not be a good idea. Instead, I would recommend having a look at [Spring Session](https://spring.io/projects/spring-session). It's incredibly easy and straightforward to use. You should make use of an external caching solution like Redis in order to being able to access the sessions from various instances of your Spring backend.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I’ll give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

Well there is no definitive answer and any answer could be too broad. In short one solution could be **role based authentication**.

It seems that you need to restrict some resources for certain privileged people, or they need another kind of authorization differ from which they already have. For this case: Role base authentication seems perfect match.

For some idea you can check this resources: 
 [Spring Security Role Based Access Authorization](https://www.journaldev.com/8748/spring-security-role-based-access-authorization-example)

Also you'll find so many resources in google search.
Key word is: [Spring Security Role Based Access Authorization](https://www.google.com/search?q=spring+security+role+based+access+authorization&rlz=1C1GIGM_enBD815BD815&oq=Spring+Security+Role+Based+Access+Authorization&aqs=chrome.0.0l2j69i60.630j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Got it. I’ll look into them. Thanks.